# Trail is completely gone

Tags: fable-3

Me and my friend was revisiting fable 3 but while we was playing we accepted a relationship mission from a villager during the mission the glow trail stopped showing up entirely and we tried to turn the glow trail off and back on and every time we change it, it changes back to medium no matter what we choose is there anyway to fix this or do i have to restart the game?

Comment: Is it completely gone or medium?

Comment: It’s completely gone we’ve tried turning it up to very high and even tried to turn it off and back on but it won’t save the changes it puts it back to medium like I never changed it

Comment: It wont let me switch it to anything else